# Flash SWF plays with answers filled already?

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe

Okay, I'm experiencing an odd issue with my flash CS5.5 program. I have one main swf which loads another swf as kind of a mini-game deal, and then continues after the swf is finished. The problem is with my external mini-game swf. In the SWF after you guess the first question right you are brought to a screen with an input/output chart and there are 2 textfields that the player has to fill out correctly in order to win points and continue. This is where I'm having the weird issues.

Whenever I run the SWF from the main SWF it starts out immediately with the fields filled out with the correct answers, and if you hit the answer button it tells you it's incorrect each time, so there is no getting past it. However, if I run the game by itself outside of the SWF by double-click opening it it runs just fine and the issue is nonexistent. Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening? Thank you all in advance.

EDIT:
I should have mentioned earlier that my main SWF is being built in Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5, and the external SWF that is having problems is a FlashDevelop 4 project.

Here is the code that loads the external mini-game swf:

```
toolLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, updateCurrentProgress);
toolLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onToolLoaderComplete);

function updateCurrentProgress(evt:ProgressEvent):void {
    var currentLoaded:Number = evt.bytesLoaded/evt.bytesTotal;
    currentLoaded = Math.round(currentLoaded*100);

    // update the preloader bar
    progressBarLoad.graphics.beginGradientFill(GradientType.LINEAR, [0xaaaaff, 0x000088], [1, 1], [0, 255], gradientMatrix, SpreadMethod.PAD);
    progressBarLoad.graphics.drawRect(1, stage.stageHeight-49, int(currentLoaded*8)-1, 48);

    // update the preloader text
    progPercentText.text = "Loading... "+currentLoaded+"%";
}

function onToolLoaderComplete(evt:Event):void {
    addChild(toolLoader);
    addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gotoQuestions);
}
```

And the game code from the external swf that is used to populate form fields (I did not code this function):

```
private function populateRule(rule:Function, startPoint:Number, increment:Number):Array{
        trace("populateRule");
        var temp:Array = new Array();
        temp.push(new Array());
        temp.push(new Array());
        for( var i:int = 0; i<5; i++){
            temp[0].push(Number(startPoint + (increment * i)));
            temp[1].push(rule(startPoint + (increment * i)));
            trace(ruleWindow.ruleTable[("in" + Number(i + 1).toString())].text);
            trace(ruleWindow.ruleTable[("out" + Number(i + 1).toString())].text);
            ruleWindow.ruleTable[("in" + Number(i + 1).toString())].text = temp[0][i].toString();
            ruleWindow.ruleTable[("out" + Number(i + 1).toString())].text = temp[1][i].toString();

        }
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Interesting issue...can you please post code though...

Comment: Another debug step you can try is make sure you didn't use = instead of an == or something like that.

Comment: I will edit my question to include some code. Just to note though, I did not code this, and it has been working great up until today for some reason. Right now I'm assuming it either must be a versioning issue, or something weird that flash is doing.

Comment: Okay I know that this is not a version issue because I can load the same SWF from within Windows explorer and it works just fine as usual. But when I run it from Flash Pro the problem happens every time now.

Comment: So if you run the mini game in windows explorer it works perfectly? But, if you run it within this other swf, it messes up?

Comment: That's exactly what's happening. Truly bizarre, indeed. Like I can open it from windows explorer and it plays just fine as I want it to, but I open my main SWF and play to the part where it loads the mini game swf and then it happens.

Comment: Okay then the loader swf should be the problem. I'm sorry again but why do you need this external swf?

Comment: I'll check the loading code, even though the problem in the external swf happens halfway through gameplay. And this external swf is one of a few mini-games that are included in the main swf. The main swf is an introduction/controller for the mini games if that makes sense.

Comment: Sure, like a loading screen. Okay have you thought of using other methods to load it like a standard loading swf if we can't figure this out. Honestly, your pushing a bunch of arrays for the answers, so that shouldn't be the problem. Maybe it does have to do with the loading somehow. Have you tried just having the answers hardcoded?

Comment: I will definitely try that. Right now I am willing to try anything because this issue is just bizarre to me, so I will try various things to see if I can get anything to work. Before I try this though, I am going to try loading an older version of the swf to see if anything has somehow changed since then.

Comment: That's a good debugging idea.